# $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\tan{0}}}$. Is it zero or undefined?

Tags: trigonometry

I had a quiz in algebra 2, and it was all about trig. There was this question that was asking to find the trig value of a fraction involving cotangent, and I ended up having $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\tan{0}}}$ after simplifying. Since $\tan(0)=0$, I answered the answer for the question was undefined because it is not allowed to have a value of $0$ in the denominator. However, the answer was $0$, changing $\tan(0)$ to $0$ after simplifying to $\tan(0)$. I think we can't keep on calculating once the denominator becomes zero. Here's what I have done.
The original fraction was $(\cot(\frac{5\pi}{2}))^2$ and I changed its form to 1/(tan(5pi/2))^2 which becomes 1/(cot(0))^2 and resulting in 1/1/(-tan (0))^2
And, I answered the answer for the question was undefined because it is not allowed to have a value of $0$ in the denominator. What's wrong in my process?

Comment: Can you post the original fraction?

Comment: I would suggest you provide the whole problem. You mention that this expression is after simplification, and the original form is what matters. But for now, operating $1/(1/0)$ is not okay.

Comment: The *function* $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1/\tan(x)}$ is identically equal to the function $x\mapsto \tan(x)$ for all $x$ such that both functions are defined.  However, the first function is not defined when $x = 0$ (that is, $0$ is not in the domain of that function).  That is to say, $\frac{1}{1/\tan(0)}$ is not defined.

Comment: Please show us *all* the work you did in simplifying $\cot^2(5\pi/2)$ down to $1/1/\tan0$.  You must have made at least one mistake.

Comment: It's not $\cot^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{2}\right)$.

It's $\left(\frac{\cot(5\pi)}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: To the OP: If you put dollar signs around your math expressions and put backslashes (\'s) in front of "tan," "cot," and "pi," you'll see a remarkable improvement in the appearance of the formulas.

Comment: $\cot(\frac{5\pi}{2})=0$, so the original expression is defined and $0$.

Comment: tan(5pi/2) = -cot (0), and  -cot 0 is -1/tan (0). -1/1/tan (0) .  I understand why the answer's 0. I don;'t know why I tried to solve in this way, but is there a process that is incorrectly done?

Comment: I was correcting what Barry had written.

Comment: @user547075  Yes, $\cot(0)$ and $\tan(5\pi/2)$ are not numbers, so the equality is not valid. Instead just use $$\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern, I agree the OP's original "(cot 5pi/2)^2" is technically ambiguous, but I think it's clear enough it should read as (cot(5pi/2))^2, not ((cot(5pi))/2)^2 (where I've added some extra parentheses to avoid even a hint of ambiguity). In TeX, $\cot^2(5\pi/2)$, or $\cot^2\left(5\pi\over2\right)$, not $\left(\cot(5\pi)\over2\right)^2$.

Comment: since tan 5pi/2 is tan (pi/2*5 +0), it becomes -cot 0. ( negative sine added because odd number is multiplied and changed to cot since it is on the 2nd quadrant, which makes only sine positive). and - cot can be expressed as - 1/tan. Right? And the whole expression becomes (-1/1/tan(0))^2. Please tell me in which part I solved it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piecing together some comments, it appears the OP did something along the lines of the following analysis:

$$\cot(5\pi/2)={1\over\tan(5\pi/2)}={1\over\tan\left({5\pi\over2}+0\right)}={1\over-\cot0}={1\over-{1\over\tan0}}$$

and then concluded (quite correctly!) that the final expression is *undefined* because you are not *ever* allowed to divide by $0$.

The resolution here is to keep in mind that the trig identity

$$\cot x={1\over\tan x}$$

technically holds only when $x$ in the domain of *both* the tangent *and* the cotangent function. So in fact the very first equality in the OP's (ostensible) analysis is technically invalid, since $5\pi/2$ is not in the domain of the tangent function. In other words, the appropriate thing to have done, as others have pointed out, is to use the *definition* of the cotangent,

$$\cot(5\pi/2)={\cos(5\pi/2)\over\sin(5\pi/2)}={0\over1}=0$$

which is simpler anyway, avoiding as it does the trig identity $\tan\left({5\pi\over2}+\theta\right)=-\cot\theta$, which I think underlies one step in what the OP did. (I'm impressed the OP got the minus sign, because I had to think really hard to see it.)

Note, I've said "technically" here a couple of times.  That's because you can often reason *informally* that $0={1\over\pm\infty}$ and/or $\pm\infty={1\over0}$, so that

$${1\over{-{1\over\tan0}}}={1\over-{1\over0}}={1\over\mp\infty}=0$$

(and it's even possible to formalize this reasoning). Alternatively, if the OP had simply kept simplifying, they would would have arrived at

$$\cot(5\pi/2)={1\over\tan(5\pi/2)}={1\over\tan\left({5\pi\over2}+0\right)}={1\over-\cot0}={1\over-{1\over\tan0}}=-\tan0=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you had, I think, is that you tried to perform the computation as
$$ \cot\left( \frac{5\pi}{2} \right)^2
= \frac{1}{\tan\left( \frac{5\pi}{2} \right)^2}. $$
In general, if $x$ is in the domain of both $\cot$ and $\frac{1}{\tan}$, then this will work and will be a perfectly reasonable argument.  That is, for such $x$, we definitely have
$$ \cot(x)^2 = \frac{1}{\tan(x)^2}. $$
However, $\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ is not in the domain of $\frac{1}{\tan}$ for any integer $k$, which means that this computation doesn't really work.

You might have better luck with your computation if you do it as follows:
$$ \cot\left( \frac{5\pi}{2} \right)^2
= \frac{\cos\left( \frac{5\pi}{2} \right)^2}{\sin\left( \frac{5\pi}{2} \right)^2}
= \frac{0}{1}
= 0.
$$

Comment: I'm really sorry, that the original fraction was cot ^2 (5pi/2), not cot (5pi/2)^2

Comment: @user547075 $\cot^2(x)$ is another notation for $\cot(x)^2$.  If you prefer, I could throw in even more parentheses, and write $[\cot(x)]^2$.  They all mean the same thing.  Unless, of course, by $\cot^(x)$, you mean $\cot(\cot(x))$; but I do not think that is what you mean.

Comment: do you see the commment I made above?  could you please answer it? I'm really curious